# abrir uma nova activity ao clicar em um item na listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Criei uma `listview` mas não estou sabendo qual comando devo fazer para meus itens abrirem uma nova `activity` para cada um.

Abaixo segue o meu código até o momento:

```
public class pg_apoio extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pg_apoio);

        ListView listadeapoio = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listadoapoio);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new listaapoioadapter(this, adicionarguias());
        listadeapoio.setAdapter(adapter);

        listadeapoio.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(pg_apoio.this, pg_bjcp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }



    private ArrayList<listaapoio> adicionarguias() {
        ArrayList<listaapoio> listaapoios = new ArrayList<listaapoio>();

        listaapoio e = new listaapoio ("Guia BJCP 2015", "guia em portugûes",R.drawable.pdf_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Lupulo", "Guia de lupulos", R.drawable.hop1);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Levedura", "Guia de leveduras", R.drawable.yeast_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Harmonização", "Guia de harmonização com cerveja", R.drawable.harmo_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Taças", "Guia de taças para cada estilo", R.drawable.beerglass_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Receitas", "Receitas prontas", R.drawable.receita_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("Links" ,"Canais de cervejeiros artesanais", R.drawable.youtubelogo_icon);

        listaapoios.add(e);
        e= new listaapoio("teste", "teste da lista", R.drawable.pdf_icon);

        return listaapoios;

    }

}
```

Comment: "itens abrirem uma nova activity para cada um" - como assim ? Isto `Intent intent = new Intent(pg_apoio.this, pg_bjcp.class); startActivity(intent);` já faz cada um abrir numa activity nova.

Answer (score 0):

No método, public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l), ele te retorna os dados do item da lista que vc clicou. 
Exemplo esse meu código pedaço de código

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            OrdemServico ordemServico = (OrdemServico) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

Estou recuperando o objeto que está relacionado ao item da listview, assim, é só eu retirar algum atributo dele.
Ex: if(ordemServico.getId = x){ vá para aqui }
Ex: if(ordemServico.getId = y){ vá para lá}

Como vai retornar aquele listaapoio e

Comment: Guilherme, muito obrigado pela dica me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Nada, qualquer dúvida que eu posso ajudar, só falar